# How To ...IIS, Reverse Proxy, URL Masking, Outbound .?

Tags: iis, rewrite, reverse-proxy

Here is the background

On our website there is a a search function which communicates with Google Search Appliance (GSA). When the user lick on search it sends the request to http://search.abc.com/query.html?&...etc.

search.abc.com is pointing to our reverse proxy server. I have created a server farm in the revers proxy server and added the GSA server. I have created rule that redirects all search.abc.com to the GSA server farm. All this works fine. So when a user searches on our website they get the result. So far all good. But they are returned with a very long url similar to the one mentioned above. I just want to shorten that url so that what the user sees on their browser is something like http://search.abc.com/query=flower instead of a very long url which shows collection names and etc.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to install IIS URL Rewrite Module on the machine then this can be done by combination of using regex and url rewrite/redirect.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I already have that installed. .but cant get it to wirk..can someone give some details